# Alternating sum in terms of its non-alternating counterpart.

Tags: summation, closed-form

Simple question, if we have a sum that has a known closed form such as the following.
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{a_k}=S_n$$
Then can we express,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{(-1)^ka_k}$$
in terms of $S_n$? If so, when?
I have tried the obvious, such as trying to construct the original sum using the alternating one, but to no end since all terms will cancel out.

I did not find anything about this on here so if anybody has any input on this or any references I'd be thankful.

Comment: Well for $\;n>0\,$ we have $\;{a_n}=S_n-S_{n-1}\;$ so that $\displaystyle\;\sum_{k=0}^{n}{(-1)^k\,a_k}=2\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\,S_k\right)-(-1)^n\,S_n\;$ which may simplify depending of your $S_n$ expression...

Comment: Sure, but I'm looking for something less obvious than that. The amount of terms the expression you've given has, tends to infinity. So as far as closed form goes, it's not really useful in the general sense.

Comment: Without further information about $S_n$ (analytical properties, whatsoever) or the regularity of $a_n$ I fear that you will remain stuck... Of course a generating function like $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{a_k}\,x^k$ would help :-)